# Mapping one dict to a new dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict object as :

```
device = {
                "id": device_object.id,
                "name": device_object.device_name,
                "children": [],
                "alias": device_object.device_alias,
                "device_type": device_type,
                "mac": device_object.mac_address,
                "current_state": device_object.host_state,
                "vendor": device_vendor
              }
```

I want this device dict to map to another dict, namely, master_device as:

```
master_device = {
                "id": device_object.id,
                "name": device_object.device_name,
                "children": [],
                "data": {
                        "alias": device_object.device_alias,
                        "device_type": device_type,
                        "mac": device_object.mac_address,
                        "current_state": device_object.host_state,
                        "vendor": device_vendor,
                        }
```

Where all the fields in sub document having key `data`, are mapped from `device` dict.

What is the 'one-liner' way to achieve this ?

**P.S.**: I don't want it to be like:

```
for (k, v) in device.iteritems():
    if k not in ["id", "name", "children"]:
        new_dict.update({k: v})
```

Or some other "for-loop" way. (I simply dont want this way)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I simply dont want this way* why not?

Comment: @TimCastelijns agree with you

Comment: *What is the 'one-liner' way to achieve this* - put it in a readable form into a function, then call it? :p

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this approach ?

```
device, master_device = {....}, {}
#for key in ['id', 'name']:
#    master_device[key] = device.pop(key)

#master_device['data'] = device


# if no 'loop'
master_device = {'id': device.pop('id'), 'name': device.pop('name'), 'data': device}
```

Comment: Or some other "for-loop" way. (I simply dont want this way). he doesnot want for loop

Comment: Maybe by `pop()`ing values from old dict to new one ?

Comment: Look mom, no for loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is all I got:

```
new_dict = ChainMap({'data': {k:device[k] for k in master_device['data'].keys()}}, master_device)
```

seems convoluted but at least it's a one liner !! :-)

This is for Python 3.3. More info on ChainMap [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap)